# cooking with cherimoya

Tags: fruit

[Cherimoya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherimoya) is an amazing delicacy that I highly recommend; however, I haven't found much culinary use for it other than eating it raw.

What's your experience on cooking with this fruit?

and on a side note, it sucks that I can't find it here in Canada :(

Comment: I suggest making this community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some recipes available on a rare fruit website, it also offers a link to an organic cherimoya orchard in California where you can order the fruit.

http://www.rain.org/~sals/eat.html

Answer (score 2):

Cherimoya ice cream is delicious. I've also had cherimoya in pancakes.